# ASP.NET C# OnSelectedIndexChanged event trigger multiple Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have this asp `DropDownList`

```
<td>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCategorySearch" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList><br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubCategorySearch" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSubCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to trigger the `OnSelectedIndexChanged` with two method 
 `ddlCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged` and `ddlSubCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged`

So, if the user triggers the `OnSelectedIndexChange`, two value method will be triggered.

But I can't solve that, how can I do that?

Comment: can be more specific with your problem

Comment: @Webruster i want know, can OnSelectedIndexChange have 2 method value? if can, how ?  
Example : 
OnSelectedIndexChange = "Value1","Value2"

Comment: @gadria hehe, im trying to populate the second dropdown with first dropdown index, so if the user select the first dropdown, the second dropdown will be changed.

Comment: no you can't but for both drop down you can keep only one method i.e. value1 or value2 and triger the code block based on `sender`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but if I understand correctly when the user changes the category value you want to fire both events?

You will be able to do this by explicitly calling the sub method from within the main category method using the following syntax

```
ddlSubCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged(sender,e)
```

If I misunderstood your question please edit it to make it a bit more clear

Edit: As per your comment above, you do not need to call the selectedindex change of the sub ddl to change its values.

You can change the datasource to the filtered one from the category dropdowns selectedindexchanged method.

I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Fill your `DataSource` for `ddlSubCategorySearch` on `ddlCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged` Event and for that you first need to fill up `DataSource` for `ddlCategorySearch` at page Load like following.

```
protected void  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      BindCategorySearch();
    }   
}

protected void BindCategorySearch()
{
    // Fill your ddlCategorySearch here. Write down your database logic to    
    //get a datasource for ddlCategorySearch 
}

protected void ddlCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    try
    {
       BindSubCategory();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

protected void BindSubCategory()
{
    try
    {
       int categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategorySearch.SelectedValue);
       //Write down here your database logic to get datasource for 
       // ddlSubCategorySearch. For Example select * from SubCategory where 
       //CategoryID = categoryID
       List<SubCategory> listSubcategories = new List<SubCategory>();
       //Fill your listCategory on base of categoryID

       ListItem li = new ListItem();
       li.Text = "--Select Sub Category--";
       li.Value = "0";
       li.Selected = true;
       ddlSubCategories.Items.Insert(0, li);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to populate one dropdown according to the other you can use something like:

```
public void ddlCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, Eventargs e){
var param = ddlCategorySearch.SelectedValue;
foreach (var item in myList)//assuming you put the elements you want inside DDL in a list
if(item.ID == param)
ddlSubCategorySearch.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text="",Value=""}); //assign DDL elements here such as item.property
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove second Dropdown selected index change and auto postback=false
 use only first dropdown selectedindex change event

```
protected void  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if (!IsPostBack)
       {
          BindCategorySearch();
        }   
    }

    protected void BindCategorySearch()
    {
        // Fill your ddlCategorySearch here. Write down your database logic to    
        //get a datasource for ddlCategorySearch 
    }

    protected void ddlCategorySearch_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
           BindSubCategory();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    protected void BindSubCategory()
    {
        try
        {
           int categoryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategorySearch.SelectedValue);
           //Write down here your database logic to get datasource for 
           // ddlSubCategorySearch. For Example select * from SubCategory where 
           //CategoryID = categoryID
           List<SubCategory> listSubcategories = new List<SubCategory>();
           //Fill your listCategory on base of categoryID

           ListItem li = new ListItem();
           li.Text = "--Select Sub Category--";
           li.Value = "0";
           li.Selected = true;
           ddlSubCategories.Items.Insert(0, li);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single function for both the DropDowns, check which one fired the event and do stuff accordingly.

```
protected void DualDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DropDownList dropDownList = sender as DropDownList;

    if (dropDownList.ID == "ddlCategorySearch")
    {
        //do stuff if ddlCategorySearch fired the event
    }
    else
    {
        //do stuff if ddlSubCategorySearch fired the event
    }
}
```